# Lie Algebra: Optimal system of one-dimensional sub-algebras of the heat equation

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, symmetry, heat-equation

This is a follow up question to [Invariants of a PDE by Lie Symmetries](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1579698/invariants-of-a-pde-by-lie-symmetries), as I tried to follow the reasoning from the book *Applications of Lie Groups to Differential Equations* (Peter J. Olver, Example 3.13 on page 204-207).

As one can show the heat equation $u_t=u_{xx}$ has the following symmetries (infinitesimal transformations):
$$ v_1 = \partial_x \quad v_2 = \partial_t \quad v_3 = u\partial_u \quad v_4 = x\partial_x +2t\partial_t$$
$$ v_5 = 2t\partial_x-xu\partial_u \quad v_6 = 4tx\partial_x+4t^2\partial_t-(x^2+2t)u\partial_u$$
$$ v_{\alpha} = \alpha(x,t)\partial_u$$

Where $\alpha(x,t)$ is a solution of the heat equation.

In example 3.13 the author wants to derive the optimal system of sub-algebras of the heat equation.

Getting the commutator table and adjoint table is not a problem. But from there on everything is not clear to me.

The author starts with the general vector
$$v=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3+a_4v_4+a_5v_5+a_6v_6$$

and directly concludes that $\eta(v)=a_4^2-4a_2a_6$ is an invariant of the full adjoint action: $\eta(Ad g(v))=\eta(v), v \in g, g \in G$

> **My first question**: How am I supposed to find this invariant?
>
> EDIT: I found out that this has to do with the killing form of the lie algebra.

Then it is stated that:

$$\tilde{v}=\sum_{i=1}^6\tilde{a}_iv_i=Ad(\exp(\alpha v_6))\circ Ad(\exp(\beta v_2))v.$$

> **My second question**: Where does this come from?

He then continues to simplify and finally gets to the set of optimal subalgebras of the heat equation

$$My last question: Can someone explain what he does?

Thank you alot for reading my question :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invariant of full adjoint action or formally called killing form is actually solution of set of linear partial differential equations of first order. I can suggest you well written article on this topic where author has described procedure for construction of such killing form. Please see [article](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/56/5/10.1063/1.4921229), this article is also available on arxiv.org.

The set of partial differential equations I am talking about are given by equation (13) on pp.053504-5 and their solution is killing form you are asking for. If you fully understood this paper you can definitely master the construction of optimal system.

Comment: Thank you mskalsi, you seem to be a master of Lie algebra :D

Comment: Thanks for complement, but I am struggling with Lie groups and algebra everyday. I believe if one have knowledge of functional analysis, differential geometry and manifolds then Lie group and Lie algebra can be better understood.

Comment: I have read through the paper and it is very easy to understand. Still the calculations are very time consuming. Do you know by any chance a way how to apply these calculations in Maple or Mathematica? A tutorial would be nice or even a file. I did't the calculations by hand but I iam not quiet sure if I have done everything correctly.

Comment: @MrYouMath Do you know how they select representative elements ?(See cases after  equation (32)). How the killing form help to select those representative elements ?